# Chef Cookbook upload

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to upload a specific cookbook from my local machine to my chef org but I am receiving the following error:

```
pwd:  /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/sensu_cookbooks/cookbooks

$ knife upload certs_tgt -c C:/Users/z068688/.chef/knife_flex_plm.rb
ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'certs_tgt' when current directory is outside the repository path.
ERROR: Current working directory is 'C:/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/sensu_cookbooks/cookbooks'.
```

Comment: You shoud `cd` to `C:/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/` then upload.

Comment: Same error again!
DHC+z068688@1ZLYGZ1 MINGW64 /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo                 
$ knife upload certs_tgt -c C:/Users/z068688/.chef/knife_flex_plm.rb
ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'certs_tgt' when current directory is outside the repository path.
ERROR: Current working directory is 'C:/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo'.

DHC+z068688@1ZLYGZ1 MINGW64 /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo

Comment: Check your `knife_flex_plm.rb` file for the "cookbook_path" parameter, or use `-o .` in your command line.

Comment: `knife cookbook upload cookbook_name  -o /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/sensu_cookbooks/cookbooks`

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: knife cookbook upload cookbook_name -o /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/sensu_cookbooks/cookbooks

Comment: @SharajAlva accepting the answer and upvoting it as an extra bonus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-o` parameter when upload cookbook to Chef-server.

`knife cookbook upload cookbook_name -o /c/Users/z068688/sharaj_repo/sensu_cookbooks/cookbooks`

Comment: Worth giving a description of what `-o` does...(and that it should be used when not working in the cookbook_path defined in knife configuration). [Documentation on knife.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) and on [knife cookbook upload](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html#upload)